# Why the material table is not getting filled from the source even the array is getting returned by the service?

Tags: angular, typescript, express, angular-material, angular6

I am using a mean stack to develop a bug tracking system.

My express.js service is returning an array of **issues**, that I am assigning to an array and then assigning that array as a dataSource to mat-table but the table is not getting populated i.e. not getting displayed. Even the array is getting returned but not the table is getting filled.

Code: Angular view

```
<mat-card>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" routerLink="/create">Create</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    <br>
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="issues">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Title</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.title}}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="responsible">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Responsible</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.responsible}}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Status</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.status}}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="severity">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Severity</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.severity}}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container  matColumnDef="actions">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="editIssue(element.id)">Edit</button>
                <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="deleteIssue(element.id)">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
    </table>
</mat-card>
```

.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import {Issues} from '../../../issue.model';
import {IssueService} from '../../../issue.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  issues: Issues[];
  displayedColumns: ['title', 'responsible', 'severity', 'status', 'actions'];
  constructor(private issueService: IssueService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
                this.fetchIssues();
          }

          fetchIssues() {
            this.issueService.getIssues().subscribe((data: Issues[]) => {
              this.issues = data;
              console.log('Data requested from the service....');
              console.log(this.issues);
          });
        }
```

Issues model:

```
export interface Issues {
    id: String;
    title: String;
    responsible: String;
    description: String;
    severity: String;
    status: String;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to declare the array of displayed columns:

In your component.ts:

```
public displayedColumns: string[] = ['title', 'responsible', 'severity', 'status'];
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d3b2g2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)